# Access all methods of same type objects in a dict()

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I want to call attributes from each element of a `dict` directly without iteration. I made a small example with `matplotlib`, where multiple figures should be created and called at the same time:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Graph(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.figures = dict()
        self.axes = dict()
        for i in [1, 2]:
            self.figures[i], self.axes[i] = plt.subplots()

    def ax(self):
        return self.axes

    def fig(self):
        return self.figures

graphic = Graph()

graphic.ax().plot([0,1,2],[5,3,1])
graphic.fig().show()
```

So each axes/figure in `graphic.ax()`/`graphic.fig()` should be called. Is there a direct approach possible?

Comment: Why don't you write a `show()` method for your `Graph` class, which iterates through all its figures and calls `show` on them? I don't think that there is any collective way except for calling `plt.show()`, which opens all created figures.

Comment: This will probably work for the `figure()` method, but the `axes()` object of matplotlib has plenty of methods, so I don't want to implement them all into my class. My goal is to produce different figure styles within `Graph()` with the same data (i.e.: one output for printed media, one for beamer presentations, ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still think that iterating over the figure and/or axes instances is the way to go. If you want something more general than implementing every function you need in your class, you could make use of the `getattr` function. Something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Graph(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.figures = dict()
        self.axes = dict()
        for i in [1, 2]:
            self.figures[i], self.axes[i] = plt.subplots()

    def ax(self):
        return self.axes

    def fig(self):
        return self.figures

    def call_ax_method(self, method, *args, **kwargs):
        for ax in self.axes.values():
            func = getattr(ax,method)
            func(*args, **kwargs)

    def call_fig_method(self, method, *args, **kwargs):
        for fig in self.figures.values():
            func = getattr(fig, method)
            func(*args,**kwargs)

graphic = Graph()

graphic.call_ax_method('plot',[0,1,2],[5,3,1], lw = 2, ls='-', marker='o')
graphic.call_fig_method('tight_layout')

plt.show()
```

By the way, the `ax` and `fig` methods in your class are not really needed, because you can access the attributes directly.

If you don't like calling your functions 'call_ax_method' and 'call_fig_method', you could write a second class that derives from `dict` and implement a `__call__` method for it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class InstanceDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)

    def __call__(self, method, *args, **kwargs):
        for inst in self.values():
            func = getattr(inst, method)
            func(*args, **kwargs)

class Graph(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.figures = InstanceDict()
        self.axes = InstanceDict()
        for i in [1, 2]:
            self.figures[i], self.axes[i] = plt.subplots()

graphic = Graph()

graphic.axes('plot',[0,1,2],[5,3,1], lw = 2, ls='-', marker='o')
graphic.figures('tight_layout')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

How to call methods from all elements of a list (a dictionary does not seem to be useful here) is shown in this question: [Is there a way to run a method for all instances of a class in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20020652/is-there-a-way-to-run-a-method-for-all-instances-of-a-class-in-python)

We may adapt it to the matplotlib case as follows. This allows e.g. to call `graphic.axes.plot([0,1,2],[5,3,1])` in order to plot this data to all stored axes.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class CallableContainer(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.values = []
    def append(self,x):
        self.values.append(x)
    def __getattr__(self, key):
        def fn(*args,**kwargs):
            return [getattr(x,key)(*args,**kwargs) for x in self.values]
        return fn


class Graph(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.figures = CallableContainer()
        self.axes = CallableContainer()
        for i in [1, 2]:
            fig,ax = plt.subplots()
            self.figures.append(fig)
            self.axes.append(ax)


graphic = Graph()

graphic.axes.plot([0,1,2],[5,3,1])
graphic.figures.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

---

However, if the real question is how to produce different style graphs, one would rather write a function, which produces a graph and call it with all desired styles, like so:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def create_graph():
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot([1,2,4])
    ax.scatter([1,2,3],[3,3,3])

styles = ["grayscale", "Solarize_Light2", "ggplot"]
for style in styles:
    with plt.style.context((style)):
        create_graph()
plt.show()
```

This creates three times the same graph with the different styles in use.

[image]